# How can I get NVVM IR (LLVM IR) from .cu - file and how to compile NVVM IR to binary?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, llvm-ir, ptx, nvvm

I have a CUDA C/C++ programm for CUDA 7.5. And as known: libNVVM Library - an optimizing compiler library that generates PTX from NVVM IR.

I can get PTX by using: `nvcc -ptx <file>.cu -o <file>.ptx`

But how can I get NVVM IR (LLVM IR) from `<file>.cu`?

And how can I compile NVVM IR (LLVM IR) or Optimized IR for the target architecture?

Do I need for this third-party libraries or programs such as: libcuda.lang, ...?

- http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3185-Building-GPU-Compilers-libNVVM.pdf

[image]

- http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0235-Compiling-CUDA-and-Other-Languages-for-GPUs.pdf

[image]

- Read more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvvm-ir-spec/index.html#ixzz3tod7pdD7

> The NVVM compiler (which is based on LLVM) generates PTX code from
>   NVVM IR.
>
> NVVM IR and NVVM compilers are mostly agnostic about the source
>   language being used. The PTX codegen part of a NVVM compiler needs to
>   know the source language because of the difference in DCI
>   (driver/compiler interface).
>
> Technically speaking, NVVM IR is LLVM IR with a set of rules,
>   restrictions, and conventions, plus a set of supported intrinsic
>   functions. A program specified in NVVM IR is always a legal LLVM
>   program. A legal LLVM program may not be a legal NVVM program.

Comment: https://github.com/apc-llc/nvcc-llvm-ir

Comment: Hi Alex, could you get LLVM IR with clang++/llvm for CUDA code? I too was wondering about this: `clang++ -S -emit-llvm -o axpy -I<CUDA install path>/samples/common/inc -L<CUDA install path>/<lib64 or lib> axpy.cu -lcudart_static -lcuda -ldl -lrt -pthread`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very short answer is that you cannot do this. NVIDIA's parser is proprietary and closed source, and they have not exposed the IR code generator in a way which can be used as you are asking about.

That said, you are not the first person to wonder about this, and you might be able to find some useful, but completely unofficial and unsupported information [here](http://github.com/apc-llc/nvcc-llvm-ir).

Comment: Thank you! I.e. *nvcc* is the compiler driver and is proprietary and closed source. But *nvopencc* is .cu-parser and based on open64 and is released under GPL, isn't it? https://habrastorage.org/files/553/c7e/300/553c7e3007ff4fba8ba815a10799a144.jpg PDF: http://www.nvidia.com/object/io_1213955090354.html

Comment: @Alex: nvopencc isn't the LVMM based parser/compiler, it is first generation, deprecated open64 based compiler that CUDA originally shipped with. That also emits PTX directly. The current LVVM based parser is proprietary and closed source and buried in libNVMM, with no external APIs or documentation which would allow access to the emitted LVMM IR code.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But if we can compile .cu-files without nvcc by using clang+llvm: `clang++ -o axpy -I<CUDA install path>/samples/common/inc -L<CUDA install path>/<lib64 or lib> axpy.cu -lcudart_static -lcuda -ldl -lrt -pthread` then can we get llvm-ir by using "clang++ **-S -emit-llvm** -o axpy -I<CUDA install path>/samples/common/inc -L<CUDA install path>/<lib64 or lib> axpy.cu -lcudart_static -lcuda -ldl -lrt -pthread"? http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html

Comment: Have you read the link I gave you? Yes clang++ can compile simple CUDA code, but the open source clang parser can't do anything like the optimisation that the NVIDIA parser can perform. So you can get some form  of IR, but how good it is or how well it will compile into PTX is something I have no experience with.